# Hadoop adding numbers

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

```
**a 10 20 30                       a  60  
                                   b  155
                                   c  50  
  b 20 45 90
  z 30 10 10
```

The above same is tab separated text file. I need the total sum of numbers row wise. And the output should be as depicted above.

I tried using the following mapper and reducer code but it's failing. Can anyone correct the code please??

Mapper code:

```
public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>{

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {
    String s = value.toString();
        for(String word:s.split("\t")){
            if(word.length()>0){
                output.collect(new Text(word),new IntWritable(1));
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }
      }
  }
}
```

Reducer Code:

```
public class WordReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    while(values.hasNext(){
        if values != null{
        sum += values.next().get();
    }
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));

    }
}
```

Comment: how it is failing? what is the result you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the wrong key and values to the reducer. That's why you can't get the sum of the numbers. You have to change your mapper code to something like this:

```html
@Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
   OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter arg3)
   throws IOException {
  
      String s = value.toString();
         String[] splits = s.split("/t");
         String newKey = splits[0].trim();
         for(int i=1;i<splits.length;i++) {
          output.collect(new Text(newKey), new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(splits[i].trim())));
         }
             

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the output.collect in the 'reducer' needs to be outside the while loop. Your code should give the desired output then.

Comment: I couldn't comment due to the reputation limit, so posted the answer along with request from the person who posted a comment previously.
Do I edit the answer?